# How to create categorical variable based on a numerical variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data

My DataFrame hase one column:

```
import pandas as pd
list=[1,1,4,5,6,6,30,20,80,90]
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':list})
```

How can I add one more column 'col2' that would contain categorical information in reference to col1:

```
if col1 > 0 and col1 <= 10 then col2 = 'xxx'
if col1 > 10 and col1 <= 50 then col2 = 'yyy'
if col1 > 50 then col2 = 'zzz'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could first create a new column `col2`, and update its values based on the conditions:

```
df['col2'] = 'zzz'
df.loc[(df['col1'] > 0) & (df['col1'] <= 10), 'col2'] = 'xxx'
df.loc[(df['col1'] > 10) & (df['col1'] <= 50), 'col2'] = 'yyy'
print df
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2
0     1  xxx
1     1  xxx
2     4  xxx
3     5  xxx
4     6  xxx
5     6  xxx
6    30  yyy
7    20  yyy
8    80  zzz
9    90  zzz
```

Alternatively, you can also apply a function based on the column `col1`:

```
def func(x):
    if 0 < x <= 10:
        return 'xxx'
    elif 10 < x <= 50:
        return 'yyy'
    return 'zzz'

df['col2'] = df['col1'].apply(func)
```

and this will result in the same output.

The `apply` approach should be preferred in this case as it is much faster:

```
%timeit run() # packaged to run the first approach
# 100 loops, best of 3: 3.28 ms per loop
%timeit df['col2'] = df['col1'].apply(func)
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 187 µs per loop
```

However, when the size of the DataFrame is large, the built-in vectorized operations (i.e. with the masking approach) might be faster.

Answer (score 27):

You could use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) as follows:

```
df['col2'] = pd.cut(df['col1'], bins=[0, 10, 50, float('Inf')], labels=['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz'])
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2
0     1  xxx
1     1  xxx
2     4  xxx
3     5  xxx
4     6  xxx
5     6  xxx
6    30  yyy
7    20  yyy
8    80  zzz
9    90  zzz
```

Comment: This is a much nicer solution than the other answers, thank you!

Comment: The docs even say "Use cut when you need to segment and sort data values into bins."

Answer (score 4):

2 ways, use a couple `loc` calls to mask the rows where the conditions are met:

```
In [309]:
df.loc[(df['col1'] > 0) & (df['col1']<= 10), 'col2'] = 'xxx'
df.loc[(df['col1'] > 10) & (df['col1']<= 50), 'col2'] = 'yyy'
df.loc[df['col1'] > 50, 'col2'] = 'zzz'
df

Out[309]:
   col1 col2
0     1  xxx
1     1  xxx
2     4  xxx
3     5  xxx
4     6  xxx
5     6  xxx
6    30  yyy
7    20  yyy
8    80  zzz
9    90  zzz
```

Or use a nested `np.where`:

```
In [310]:
df['col2'] = np.where((df['col1'] > 0) & (df['col1']<= 10), 'xxx', np.where((df['col1'] > 10) & (df['col1']<= 50), 'yyy', 'zzz'))
df

Out[310]:
   col1 col2
0     1  xxx
1     1  xxx
2     4  xxx
3     5  xxx
4     6  xxx
5     6  xxx
6    30  yyy
7    20  yyy
8    80  zzz
9    90  zzz
```